Posit connect server timing out before config timeout
I have a posit connect server running on an ubuntu VM that does some heavy data processing before returning, however it is timing out consistently after taking about 4 minutes.
Checking the rstudio-connect.gcfg config file however shows I already have the connection timeout set to
[Scheduler]
InitTimeout = 120s
ReadTimeout = 4h
ConnectionTimeout = 4h

Does anyone know why I am encountering a timeout like this?
I am hitting the endpoint from my local RStudio instance but strangely I get the error message

"Timeout was reached: [endpoint name] SSL/TLS connection timeout."

right when the data finishes processing.
I tried changing the gcfg and restarting the VM but nothing seems to change it.
